# Why aren't my threads listed in Visual Studio Code GDB [C++]?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb, vscode-debugger

According to the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug#_multithreaded-debugging), threads should be listed under the "Call Stack" panel. However, I only see this: [("Call Stack" panel only showing one thread)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdlYk.png)

Anyone know how to fix this? Maybe a setting somewhere I'm missing that will show all threads?

Comment: Your screenshot appears to show four threads in Call Stack window. What again seems to be the problem?

Comment: Hmm... you're right, thanks. I don't know what I was thinking. Anyway, I'm not sure why there are 4 threads since my program should only have 1 main thread and 2 spawned threads. Also VSCode is showing "[Unknown/Just-In-Time compiled code] Unknown Source" for threads 1, 2, 4 rather than the call stack. I suppose these are off-topic questions that I'll make a new post about.